# How to install zeal in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, zeal

I am new to ubuntu and I am using 12.04 version of it. How to install zeal on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apt-repository `ppa:jerzy-kozera/zeal-ppa` is deprecated

using follow in `ubuntukylin-14.04.2-desktop-amd64` will be better

> - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
> - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeal-developers/ppa
> - sudo apt-get update
> - sudo apt-get install zeal

Answer (score 8):

Zeal has an official PPA. You can use that to install it.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zeal-developers/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install zeal
```

Now you can search for `zeal` app or you can launch it from terminal using `zeal` command.

This install zeal without any problems. I have used other PPA's also but they failed because of unmet dependencies.

Comment: This also works for Linux Mint.